# Align input[submit] with text field

Tags: css, alignment

I'm a CSS/HTML newbie and have tried to do research on this but am stumped. I've seen others with a similar problem, but their submit button and text field are only slightly misaligned. Mine is vertical but I want it horizontal.
I tried adding display: inline-block to both the text field and submit button elements, but it didn't fix the issue.

Here is the embed code for the form:

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="https://julienkozak.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?
u=f46b7a895f8d332e0127067ad&amp;id=4fbc88f22f" method="post" id="mc-
embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" 
target="_blank" novalidate>
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

<div class="mc-field-group">

<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-
EMAIL" placeholder="e-mail address">
</div>
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
<div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none">
</div>
<div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none">
</div>
</div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - 
do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input 
type="text" name="b_f46b7a895f8d332e0127067ad_4fbc88f22f" tabindex="-1" 
value=""></div>
<div class="clear" ><input type="submit" value="Get Updates" 
name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

The rest of the code you see is the CSS :

```
/* MAILCHIMP top form  */
#mc_embed_signup {

text-align: center;
width: 300px;

}

/* Styles the header text above the inputs */
#mc_embed_signup h2 {
font-size: 18px;
margin: 0 0 20px;
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
}

/* Adds extra space around the input boxes */
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group {
padding: 10px 0;
}

/* Styles the input boxes */
#mc_embed_signup  input {
width: 200px;
background: white;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 0px;
display: inline-block;
}

/* Styles the subscribe button */
#mc_embed_signup .button {
background-color: gray;
color: #ffffff;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100px;
height: 40px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

julienkozak.com/ The form is at the top of this page.
Thank you so much for your patience with me.

Comment: If any of the answers have helped please consider accepting one, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

## Have you considered using bootstrap?

You could also use bootstrap's row functionality to dynamically set the fields of your div tag to a certain part of the page. This has the added benefit of making your page responsive to a variety of screens and monitors.

[image: pic]

Comment: Thank you Neil, I had never heard of this until now. I'll have to learn about it.

Comment: You can find some excellent resources on Bootstrap at Free Code Camp and W3Schools. https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/use-responsive-design-with-bootstrap-fluid-containers and https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox on the wrapping div `mc_embed_signup_scroll` using display:flex. I put margin-top:10px on the button to align it with the input field.

```css
/* MAILCHIMP top form  */

#mc_embed_signup {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}


/* Styles the header text above the inputs */

#mc_embed_signup h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Adds extra space around the input boxes */

#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group {
  padding: 10px 0;
}


/* Styles the input boxes */

#mc_embed_signup input {
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  
}


/* Styles the subscribe button */

#mc_embed_signup .button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top:10px;

}

#mc_embed_signup_scroll{display:flex}
```

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
  <form action="https://julienkozak.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?
u=f46b7a895f8d332e0127067ad&amp;id=4fbc88f22f" method="post" id="mc-
embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

      <div class="mc-field-group">

        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-
EMAIL" placeholder="e-mail address">
      </div>
      <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none">
        </div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - 
do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_f46b7a895f8d332e0127067ad_4fbc88f22f" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
      <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Get Updates" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```